# Replace legend on the c3.js graph

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, angular-material, c3.js

I'm trying to replace default c3 legend with the new controls from Angular Material. Please take a look at the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m7dxmjjq/2/)

Under the graph there is default c3 legend which I want to replace with controls above graph. Any ideas how to do that? 
Thanks.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial']);

myApp.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.data = {
        data1: true,
        data2: true
    }

   $scope.chart_grid_lines = c3.generate({
        bindto: '#chart1',
        data: {
            columns: [
                ['data1', 30,200,100,400,150,250],
                ['data2', 50,20,10,40,15,25]
            ]
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `ng-change` to a function like so

```
<md-switch class="md-secondary" ng-model="data.data1" aria-label="Switch 1" ng-change="updateChart()">
```

`updateChart()` would look at `$scope.data` and use the C3 API to hide / show the series, like so

```
$scope.updateChart = function() {
    if ($scope.data.data1)
        $scope.chart_grid_lines.show(['data1']);
    else
        $scope.chart_grid_lines.hide(['data1']);

    if ($scope.data.data2)
        $scope.chart_grid_lines.show(['data2']);
    else
        $scope.chart_grid_lines.hide(['data2']);
}
```

You might also want to hide the C3 legend using `legend.show`

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/db2Lgs7x/

Comment: It works only after the first load. After refreshing (reloading) the browser window, it' doesn't work (Chrome, Opera) :/ Is it possible to track change with the $watch function? Thanks.

Comment: yep, it's possible. If you are watching data, just make sure you do a deep watch - http://jsfiddle.net/vog1cnv2/